How to Efficiently Handle and Display Over 1000 Plots with User Input in Jupyter Notebook with VS Code
I'm running an analysis that requires plotting data and having a human (engineer) decide whether to accept the fitting based on their judgment. The dataset is large, with over 1000 plots, and user input is necessary for each plot. However, I'm encountering a problem where Jupyter Notebook stops displaying outputs after reaching 500 outputs, which hinders my analysis.
Is there a way to efficiently handle and display such a large number of plots while still allowing for user input for each plot in Jupyter Notebook? Below is a simplified version of my code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants for column names
ID_COLUMN = 'ID'
Z_COLUMN = 'Z'
X_COLUMN = 'X'
Y_COLUMN = 'Y'

# Sample DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({
    ID_COLUMN: np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], 1000),
    Z_COLUMN: np.random.choice([10, 20, 30], 1000),
    X_COLUMN: np.random.rand(1000) * 100,
    Y_COLUMN: np.random.rand(1000) * 50
})

def plot_data(data):
    unique_ids = data[ID_COLUMN].unique()
    
    for data_id in unique_ids:
        filtered_data = data[data[ID_COLUMN] == data_id]
        unique_z_values = filtered_data[Z_COLUMN].unique()
        
        for z_value in unique_z_values:
            filtered_data_z = filtered_data[filtered_data[Z_COLUMN] == z_value]
            
            plt.figure()
            plt.plot(filtered_data_z[X_COLUMN], filtered_data_z[Y_COLUMN])
            plt.title(f'ID: {data_id}, Z: {z_value}')
            plt.xlabel(X_COLUMN)
            plt.ylabel(Y_COLUMN)
            plt.show()
            
            user_input = input(f'Accept plot for ID {data_id} at Z {z_value}? (y/n): ')
            if user_input.lower() == 'abort':
                return

# Running the plotting function
plot_data(data)

Details:
Each plot must be reviewed and accepted by a human.
The dataset results in over 1000 plots.
Jupyter Notebook stops displaying outputs after 500 plots, which disrupts the analysis process.
Questions:
How can I manage and display more than 500 plots in Jupyter Notebook efficiently?
Are there any best practices or alternative approaches to handle such large-scale plotting with user input?
Thank you for your help!

I do not have a solution for your particular problem, but maybe an idea: what I did in the past was building an interactive GUI in the notebook, using event handling with matplotlib, in combination with buttons from Jupyter widgets. With this, you could for example show one plot at a time and then have the user (1) tick an "approve" checkbox and (2) click on a "next" button to show the next plot in the same figure. It is a bit tedious, but possible.

Hello, this may have performance issues. You can try using batching and then using interactive widgets to manage these plots. For example, using ipywidgets to create interactive controls.
